# how to use both sim to send a sms on single button click .?

Tags: android

I have used below code to send a SMS programmatically on a button click.
But that code send sms with only SIM1 (default sim of device) 
but I wand to send that sms using both sim when app running on a duel SIM phone.

```
   private void sendSMS() {

    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> smsString = sms.divideMessage("xxxx");
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage("99999", null, smsString, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(), "Click send to subscribe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch(Exception exp){
        Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(), "SMS sending failed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: @AHoneyBustard Thnkss., it ok now

Comment: please anyone answer me